How to interact with the elements of website made in Reactjs?
I am trying to focus on a div with role textbox on a website made in reactjs but nothing is working.
I have tried this:
async function focusOnElement(selector) {
  let element = undefined;
  while (!element) {
    element = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).at(-1);
    await delay(1000);
  }
  if (!element) {
    console.warn("Element not found for focusing.");
    return;
  }

  element.focus();
  
 
  const focusEvent = new Event("focus", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
  element.dispatchEvent(focusEvent);

  console.log(`Focused on element: ${selector}`);
}


But it didn't work.
I have also tried this:
async function focusOnElement(selector) {
  let element = undefined;
  while (!element) {
    element = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).at(-1);
    await delay(1000); // Wait for the element to exist
  }
  if (!element) {
    console.warn("Element not found for focusing.");
    return;
  }

  // Focus on the element explicitly
  element.focus();

  // Manually trigger React's synthetic focus event
  const reactKey = Object.keys(element).find(
    (key) =>
      key.startsWith("_reactProps$") || key.startsWith("_reactFiber$")
  );

  if (reactKey) {
    const props = element[reactKey];
    if (props && props.onFocus) {
      // Dispatch a synthetic focus event that React can handle
      props.onFocus({
        target: element,
        currentTarget: element,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      });
    }
  }

  console.log(`Focused on element: ${selector}`);
}


But still cant focus
Website is https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/options/mail/rules click on Add new rule and on condition select From and the div that i want to focus on will be visible

Friend, here's a practical example of how to get an element through its attribute(s):


// Selects more text entry points...
const selector = 'textarea,input[type="text"],[role="textbox"]';

async function focusOnElement ( selector, rootElement )
{
  const element = (rootElement ?? document).querySelector(selector);

  if ( element != null )
  {
    element.focus();
    element.dispatchEvent
    (
      new Event('focus', { bubbling: true, cancelable: true })
    );
  }
  
  return element;
}

// Examples of how to use:
addEventListener
(
  'DOMContentLoaded', async event =>
  {
    // Focus on page load (ready content).
    const element = await focusOnElement(selector);
    
    document.querySelectorAll('.focusOnFirstButton').forEach
    (
      element => element.addEventListener
      (
        'click', async event =>
        {
          const element = await focusOnElement(selector, event.target.parentElement);

          console.log('Focused content:', element.textContent?.length ? element.textContent : element.value?.length ? element.value : '');
        }
      )
    );
    
    console.clear();
    console.log('Focused content:', element?.textContent?.length ? element?.textContent : element?.value?.length ? element?.value : '');
  }
);
.TB
{
  outline: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
<div>
  <div role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Some Label" tabindex="0" class="TB" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" style="max-height: 189px;">DIV CONTENT 1</div>
  <div><textarea>TEXT AREA 1</textarea></div>
  <div><input type="text" value="INPUT VALUE 1" /></div>
  <button class="focusOnFirstButton">Focus on First</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<form type="modal">
  <div><textarea>TEXT AREA 2</textarea></div>
  <div><input type="text" value="INPUT VALUE 2" /></div>
  <div role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Some Label" tabindex="0" class="TB" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" style="max-height: 189px;">DIV CONTENT 2</div>
  <input type="button" class="focusOnFirstButton" value="Focus on First" />
</form>
<hr/>
<form type="modal">
  <div><input type="text" value="INPUT VALUE 3" /></div>
  <div><textarea>TEXT AREA 3</textarea></div>
  <div role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Some Label" tabindex="0" class="TB" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" style="max-height: 189px;">DIV CONTENT 3</div>
  <input type="button" class="focusOnFirstButton" value="Focus on First" />
</form>



NOTE that the example above will only select the first element that matches the selector. The main issue to solve your problem is actually the selector itself:
focusOnElement('textarea,input[type="text"],[role="textbox"]')

Also, I think your code is a bit problematic... See the comments in the snippet below.


async function focusOnElement(selector) {
  // let element = undefined;
  
  // This is really high-cost logic.
  /*
  while (!element) {
    element = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).at(-1);
    await delay(1000);
  }
  if (!element) {
    console.warn("Element not found for focusing.");
    return;
  }
  */
  
  //element.focus();
  
  // Is there a need for this?
  /*
  const focusEvent = new Event("focus", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
  element.dispatchEvent(focusEvent);

  console.log(`Focused on element: ${selector}`);
  */
  
  // NEW LOGIC: Only select the first element that matches
  // the selector provided in the parameter.
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  {
    const focusEvent = new Event('focus', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});

    element.focus();
    element.dispatchEvent(focusEvent);
  };
  
  return element;
}

focusOnFirstButton.addEventListener
(
  'click', async event =>
  {
    const element = await focusOnElement('textarea,input[type="text"],[role="textbox"]');
    
    console.log('Focused content:', element.textContent?.length ? element.textContent : element.value?.length ? element.value : '');
  }
);

document.addEventListener
(
  'DOMContentLoaded', async event =>
  {
    const element = await focusOnElement('textarea,input[type="text"],[role="textbox"]');
    
    console.clear();
    console.log('Focused content:', element.textContent?.length ? element.textContent : element.value?.length ? element.value : '');
  }
);
.TB
{
  outline: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
<div role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Some Label" tabindex="0" class="TB" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" style="max-height: 189px;">DIV CONTENT</div>
<div><textarea>TEXT AREA</textarea></div>
<div><input type="text" value="INPUT VALUE" /></div>
<button id="focusOnFirstButton">Focus on First</button>




No it didn't work
